# package unable to consume from a partition

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I'm not able to consume from a topic and I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my code or my kafka configuration. The problem I'm getting is it's stuck on the print statement of "Starts" so it's not receiving a message from the channel <-partitionConsumer.Messages().

These are the steps I took for my kafka setup (https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) with some messages in them, and I know for sure they exist because when I run the following command I see values.

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --partition 0 --topic test
>   --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --offset earliest
>
> 1. bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
> 2. bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
> 3. bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
> 4. bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

```
func RetrieveConsumed() (int){
    consumer, err := sarama.NewConsumer([]string{"localhost:9092"}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR")
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := consumer.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR")
        }
    }()

    partitionConsumer, err := consumer.ConsumePartition("test", 0, sarama.OffsetOldest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR")
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := partitionConsumer.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR")
        }
    }()

    // Trap SIGINT to trigger a shutdown.
    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt)

    consumed := 0
    ConsumerLoop:
        for {
            fmt.Println("Starts")
            select {
            case msg := <-partitionConsumer.Messages():
                fmt.Printf("Consumed message offset %d\n", msg.Offset)
                consumed++
            case <- partitionConsumer.Errors():
                break ConsumerLoop
            case <-signals:
                break ConsumerLoop
            }
        }

        fmt.Printf("Consumed: %d\n", consumed)
        return consumed
}
```